# Load same list activity with different data in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview in android that I am populating with data. What I want to do is, when any of the item in the list is clicked, i want to load the same list activity but with different data based on the item that was clicked. Can anyone throw pointers at how to do this?

So my data can be thought like a tree where I start from the root and can navigate to leaf data via a list.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when click the item, load the data you want to refresh, then call adapter.notifyDatasetChange(), the adapter is what you set to the listview

for example, your data is in a list, you should:
1 put new data in the list
2 call adapter.notifyDatasetChange()

Answer (score 1):

I think you can send the item type throught the Intent to the activity that you want to display.

**first activity**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("itemId", id);
```

**list activity**:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String itemId = getStringExtra("itemId");

if (itemId == "something1"){
  load1();
} else {
  load2();
}
```